# How to change the size of item-avatar in ionic?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am developing an app using ionic framework. I need to display an image in the side menu header. I have used **item-avatar** to display the image. Here is the code.

```
<ion-side-menus>
<ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-calm style="height:200px" >
        <div class="list" >
            <a class="item item-avatar">
                <img src="some image source">
                <p>This is an image</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
</ion-side-menu>

<ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-list >
        <!-- Links to the pages that must contain the side menu. -->
        <ion-item href="#/side-menu24/page1">Page1</ion-item>
        <ion-item href="#/side-menu24/page2"> Page2</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-side-menu-content>
```

How do I change(increase) the size of the image displayed in the item-avatar? I was suggested the following CSS:

```
.list .item-avatar{ 
width: 20px !important; 
height : 60px !important;}
```

This increases the content size(size allocated to the div tag) of the item-avatar as a whole but the image size remains the same. Is there any way to increase the size of the image displayed inside the item-avatar?

Comment: Do you want to zoom your image?

Comment: No. Just to increase the display size of the image.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The item avatar has a default max-width and max-height property. You can find it in the ionic.css file. 
You can either change it over there or in your CSS just add:

```
.item-avatar  {     
width:100% !important;  
height : 100% !important;  
max-width: 100px !important;  //any size
max-height: 100px !important; //any size 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I changed it in the ionic.css file.

Answer (score 12):

With ionic 3 I found the other answers to not work when I put them into my page's SCSS file, this instead worked for me, and is a mild modification of Vairav's answer.

```
ion-avatar img  {
width:100% !important;
height : 100% !important;
max-width: 100px !important;  //any size
max-height: 100px !important; //any size
}
```

Comment: I only needed the width and height attributes for it to work

Answer (score 12):

Best solution I found for **Ionic 4** :

```
ion-avatar { 
    width: 100px;  
    height: 100px;  
}
```

Answer (score 11):

In **Ionic v4** you only need to specify the max's.

```
ion-avatar {
    max-width: 25px;
    max-height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Did not work for me, but just giving width/height (without max-) works

Comment: The only custom CSS element is --border-radius so using either max-width, max-height or width, height as per any usual element will work as normal if you don't have any other blocking or inline overriding style. Ionic gets updated pretty frequently so be sure to check docs first over Stack: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/avatar

Answer (score 1):

use font-size in place of width and height

```
.list .item-avatar
{
font-size:20px; /* as big size as you want */
}
```

Comment: This works if I use an icon instead of image. But the image size still does not change.

Comment: if you use image then you have to give width height instead of icon

Answer (score 0):

This was enough in my case:

```
.item-md ion-avatar img {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```